# create startup disk for windows inside linux

Tags: usb

I am trying to install Windows on my laptop but Ubuntu is the only OS I have in my house and Ubuntu won't let me turn my external HDD into a Windows Vista installer drive.

First I wish to have a graphical interface as the terminal is not a strong point for me so I would like NO text entry as it's too tedious and confusing none of the software. All I can find is about Ubuntu, it's software to make an Ubuntu installer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/utopic/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-ubuntu-freshlight-utopic.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

Copy-Paste(line-by-line) that into the terminal and run WinUSB. It's all pretty easy from there.

Source:
https://askubuntu.com/a/381560/371553

Comment: confusing has hit now lol

sed: can't read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-freshlight-trusty.list: No such file or directory

I got that come up

Comment: Did you add the repository? Could you post a picture of your terminal (using the Screenshot application)?

Comment: an error came up sorry I hit enter thinking of line break but it posted it sorry lol the error is the confusing part btw I'm running Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Also, since you are on 14.10, try the second line again, but replace "trusty" with "utopic".

Comment: thanks lol here is the terminal screen shot

http://imgur.com/wnQ2w5K

Comment: Replaced trusty with utopic and it still says no file or directory

Comment: Please upload an image with "utopic" also.

Comment: Uploaded here http://imgur.com/DzejYJ5

Comment: Can you confirm by going to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and seeing if there is a file named `colingille-freshlight-..`?

Comment: I went to that location and executed ls command and here is the printscreen http://imgur.com/CHzgpR6

Comment: Ok. Try the second line now. Looks like your file name changed and hence it gave the error.

Comment: I looked at the second line and add the -ubuntu- to it and something happened but no text came up

Comment: Ok. Now run the third and fourth commands.

Comment: done that and its installed thank you so much it worked this time :) much appreciated yoda your a pc saver lol I was going to start to break my pc really helpful :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/wily/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-ubuntu-freshlight-wily.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about what this is supposed to do. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)