# Create startup disk for windows 8.1 inside Ubuntu 14.01

Tags: live-usb

I've installed Ubuntu on my laptop but
didn't know that my windows OS would be removed (even tho it says so while doing this process!!!) <--Had to say this, sorry :/

...Just a Drone after all...

Now I've been trying to reinstall windows with Ubuntu already installed.

I've tried a lot of way's but I couldn't fix it. (Go figure)

(Blame the other guy) That's it :)
My problem is the same as this person (Check the link) [create startup disk for windows inside linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583795/create-startup-disk-for-windows-inside-linux/724827?noredirect=1#comment1072898_724827)

Again when I try this step /etc/apt/sources.list.d
I can not see the file colingille-freshlight-..
as u can see on the photo[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/choKO.png)

Comment: You have to disable fast boot in your windows settings or windows will  be in a hibernated state when you try to install ubuntu.  When windows is in a hibernated state during ubuntu install, windows will be overwritten and this is what happened to you. If you want to install ubuntu with windows installed, you must disable fast boot and then shut windows down properly before the installation, do not hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I'd start with windows and than set up a dual boot for Ubuntu...Never heard anyone to it the other way around...When you install Ubuntu it will warn you that the HDD or SSD will be losing all data...So no one can help with this, dunno about the other guy's issue but your's seems to be, well your own fault...Don't stress windows is free now so just download a new OS and start over...Maybe when you have that set up do it the right way.

Anyway this isn't going to help you much...I'll check for a link...Bet there's not a change in hell Ubuntu has the set up for that sadly...As I thought...START OVER...Ubuntu isn't a joke, people seem to forget that a lot these days.

Comment: what is the new os ?

Comment: Download windows 7 (which is free) I think XD
or which ever new OS of windows you got...Install that and than set up the dual boot like it's suppose to be done. Cheers

Comment: i already downloaded Win8.1_English_x64.iso

Comment: Well than that's what you have to do, wipe the HDD again but install win 8.1...Than move on from there as I said before.

Comment: u means I follow the dual boot  . i cant create usb bootable  .

Comment: my windows was 8.1 i have a windows 7 cd bootable ,can i use win7 .

Comment: I haven't found a single person saying they've installed windows on a Linux based distro  so YEAH I'm saying that you will have to reinstall windows 1st..

Comment: Use whatever version of Windows you have a valid key for on that computer. To get the 8.1 installer on a usb, it looks like [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/487970/495716) answer should work.

Comment: I've installed windows on an ubuntu machine, you just need to reinstall grub or run boot repair after installing windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, reinstall Windows cleanly first and then install Ubuntu as dual boot.

Even if you succeeded in Windows over Ubuntu, Windows master boot record will install over GRUB and will not recognize your Ubuntu partition. Installing Ubuntu second, will install GRUB over MBR which will detect both your Ubuntu and Windows partition.

Also you have to be consistent with boot types. That is, if Windows is UEFI, Ubuntu needs to be UEFI. If Windows is legacy, Ubuntu needs to be legacy. There is the case where you can install Windows with UEFI boot, then disable UEFI, then install Ubuntu as legacy. But if you have UEFI, you should install both Windows and Ubuntu with UEFI.

Comment: but when I reboot the system by win cd after restart( cant find operation )

Comment: and i cant do any thing i have to turn off my laptop an turn on again ,after that  I cant boot my ubuntu as well i have to reinstall agin my ubutu

Comment: When you install Windows cleanly, you should have wiped Ubuntu, so of course Ubuntu will not boot. If you are using Windows 7, you do have to disable fastboot, secure boot, and enable legacy boot because Windows 7 cannot install with those modes on, only Windows 8 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Win8.1_English_x64.iso file and select burn to disk. Ubuntu will burn the disk and it will be bootable. You will need to burn this to a blank DVD.

Next, use your Ubuntu installation media to boot up the computer in a live session and choose "Try ubuntu without installing".

Open up the application "Gparted", and create a partition to put windows on. The partition must be NTFS format and it must be a "primary" type partition and not "extended".

Install windows when you are done.

After you reinstall windows, run bootrepair.